# Sass - check variable for user input

Tags: variables, sass, user-input

I'm working on building out a set of common SASS mixins. Some of these mixins have 5-10 variables, all with default values. I'd like a way to check whether a user has input values - **not the variable contents, but whether there has been an actual user input.** For example, in the following mixin:

```
@mixin backdrop($color: #000) {
    background-color: $color;
}
```

If a user, in their own code, calls:

```
@include backdrop(#000);
```

There should be **no warning.** Even though they have input the same value as the default, there is still a user input, so `@warn` is not required. However, if the user calls:

```
@include backdrop;
```

There should be a warning, to ensure the user knows about the possible variables.

This is a lot more useful for mixins with more variables. For example, let's say I have a standard button for my site:

```
@mixin button($background: #222, $textcolor: #fff, $corner-round: 5px) {
  background-color: $background;
  color: $textcolor;
  border-radius: $corner-round;
}
```

A user could input `@include button;` and they'd get a dark grey button with white text and 5px rounded corners. Often, if someone is using a mixin like this, which they didn't write themselves, they might assume - seeing `@include button;` used elsewhere in the code - that there were no variables. And I know best practice is to check an unfamiliar mixin for variables - but not everyone does this. So they might go in and type:

```
@include button;
background-color: #444;
```

to get a lighter grey button. I'd like to be able to warn a user who calls the mixin and provides no variables that, "Hey, there's some variables provided that you might want to use!" - that way, if they want to override the defaults, they can do it with as few lines of code as possible.

Does anyone know if this kind of user-input check is possible with SASS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @mixin backdrop($color: #000) { ... }
>   @include backdrop(#000); // there should be no warning
>   @include backdrop; // warning

Within the mixin you can't distinguish anymore if the value is given by the user or initialized with the default value. A way to solve this issue is to set a default value within the mixin signature that won't get passed in by the user. At this point I assume that you want to allow a user to get rid of any warnings by explicitly setting a value to `null` when using the mixin so that the default value is used (in other words: `null` is a valid user input to tell the mixin *Yes, I'm aware of the variables but please use the default value*).

We can then change the mixin signature to use `false` as *initial* default value so that we can see within the mixin if the value has been set or not. The *actual* default value is then set within the mixin and used only if the user has not provided any input. The code could then be like the following:

```
@function warn-on-false($mixin, $value, $default) {
  @if $value == false {
    @warn "Hey, there's some variables provided ... see mixin: #{$mixin}.";
    @return $default;
  } 
  @else if $value == null {
    @return $default;
  }
  @return $value;
}

@mixin button($background: false, $corner-round: false) {
  background-color: warn-on-false("button()", $background, "#222");
  border-radius: warn-on-false("button()", $corner-round, 5px);
}

.class {
  @include button; // warns for $background and $corner-round
}

.class2 {
  @include button("#444"); // warns for $corner-round
}

.class3 {
  @include button(null, 5px); // no warning
}
```

Console output (3x):

```
WARNING: Hey, there's some variables provided ... see mixin: button().
     on line 3 of style.scss, in `button'
     from line 28 of style.scss`
```

CSS output:

```
.class {
  background-color: "#222";
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.class2 {
  background-color: "#444";
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.class3 {
  background-color: "#222";
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

---

This is yet just some food for thoughts that shows that and how it *could* be done. You could also think about modifying the warn-function so that it loops over a list of values, you call it then once within every mixin and only get a maximum of one warning per mixin call (in the above you get two warnings for `.class`). What I would do is to give advice to the user in the warning message and tell that `null` should explicitly be passed to the mixin if the default value should be used.

Comment: That is an extremely elegant solution, and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I can understand what you're trying to do but I don't think it is actually possible.

What you intend to do is CSS core, using a *mixin* in this way is essentially just a different way of writing a *class*.

Also getting a warning every time an *@include* is used would be very verbose.

Comment: That's a good point, about too many warnings becoming too verbose. I might go back through the code and only use this type of warning on certain high-priority or heavy-use mixins, and include a Readme.txt file or more detailed comments for the rest. Thanks!